# Custom object re-initialization when i pass it to WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

So I'm just currently trying to get the hang of passing a custom object to a WCF service. I assume I have the format right, but I might not since I'm still pretty new to WCF services and what not. My Service code looks as follows

ILetsHost.cs

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "hiThere")]
public interface ILetsHost
{
    [OperationContract]
    Foo doSome(Foo f, int _i);
}

[DataContract]
public class Foo
{
    [DataMember]
    public int i { get; set; }

    public Foo()
    {
        i = 1;
    }

    public Foo(Foo f)
    {
        this.i = f.i;
    }

    public void doSome(int _i)
    {
        i = i + _i;
    }
}
```

LetsHost.cs

```
public class LetsHost : ILetsHost
{
    public Foo doSome(Foo f, int _i)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("f.i is: " + f.i.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show("i is: " + _i.ToString());
        Foo a = (Foo)new Foo(f);
        a.i = f.i;
        a.doSome(_i);
        MessageBox.Show("a.i is: " + a.i.ToString());
        return f;
    }
}
```

The host code looks as follows:

```
string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
        string endPoint = "http://" + hostName + ":8000";

        Uri ep = new Uri(endPoint);
        ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(HostingServices.LetsHost), ep);

        using (host)
        {
            host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(HostingServices.ILetsHost), new BasicHttpBinding(), "Service");
            host.Open();

            Console.WriteLine("Endpoint: " + endPoint + "/Service");
            Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate");
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

What I did was the to separate the my Host project and Client project. I then proceeded to add(copy) the ILetsHost.cs item to the client project. The client code looks as follows:

```
EndpointAddress ep = new EndpointAddress("http://Stean-PC:8000/Service");
        ILetsHost proxy = ChannelFactory<ILetsHost>.CreateChannel(new BasicHttpBinding(), ep);

        Foo a = new Foo();
        a.doSome(2);
        Console.WriteLine("Value before server pass: " + a.i.ToString());

        a = proxy.doSome(a, 3);
        Console.WriteLine("Value after server pass: " + a.i.ToString());

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Now the problem is this. You see the first messagebox in LetsHost.cs, well it's telling me that the Foo abject I passed has an i-value of 0. Where it is supposed to have a value of three. And then the third messagebox is telling me that the Foo object (a) I created has an i-value of 3, but when it returns to the client project the i-value of the returned Foo object (a) is again 0. I have no idea where I'm going wrong. Any help whatsoever would be appreciated, thank-you.

Comment: You can't do this.  The object is serialized when it is passed to the web service, so it is a copy of what you sent, not a reference to the original object. You can have the web service return an object of the same type, and use that, but the client object and its reconstituted version on the server have no connection.

Comment: @dbugger so I can't do this at all?

Comment: The web service cannot change properties of a client-side object, so no, what you are expecting to happen will not work.

Comment: @dbugger you should post Your comment as an answer so it can be accepted :)

Comment: @ShirazBhaiji Thanks, but it's not that exciting.